# How to change the action on a form in a popup?

Tags: jquery, window

I have the jQuery included that will change the action of the form on the popup page but I want to have the window opener be able to control the form action of the popup... Is this possible?

popup HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad=chgAction();>
<script>
function chgAction() {
$('#search').attr('action', 'myNewActionTarget.html');
}
</script>
<base href="http://vahud.com/">
<form id="search" method="GET" action="doWork.php">
First Name <input type="text" name="fname" value="Tom"><br>
Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" value="Chambers"><br>
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is in my  window opener.. and above is the form in the myform.htm that will be the popup.. I want to be able to move the action changer down here to the window opener page.. to get the same result I get with it in the form..

window opener JS:

```
window.open('myform.htm','mywindow','width=300,height=300');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to wrap your javascript in a document.ready so that it binds after the form exists.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var popup = window.open('/' + window.URL_PREFIX + '/', '_blank');
   popup.onload = function() {
    $(popup.document.body).attr('action', 'myNewActionTarget.html');
  };
  chgAction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <base href="http://vahud.com/">
  <form id="search" method="GET" action="doWork.php">
    First Name
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="Tom">
    <br>Last Name
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="Chambers">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Search">
  </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7gz2uv1w/

Comment: I may not have made myself clear, but what you provided would be great but its not a remote control.. what I tried to explain is the form will be a popup on the page and the page that pops the form up will be the one with the javascript or jqurey script that will change the action.  The action changer will not be in the actual popped up form page but in the page that generated the popup the parent.. So mine worked fine.. for changing the action I just could not figure out how to make it work remotely..  sorry if I was not real clear.

Comment: Oh, I thought what you posted was the popup. Where is the popup code? You are trying to control the action within the popup from the original page? I've edited my answer to show remotely controlling a popup window.